# Read the hour and minute from a time string

Tags: java, string, int

There is one problem String has ":"

```
 String time = "21:45";
```

How does convert this string to two int:

```
int hour = 21;
int minute = 45;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight forward, non-validating way:

```
String[] parts = time.split(":");
int hour = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int minute = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

Comment: Doesn't get much simpler than this.

Comment: In fact, it should get more complex to validate the time, with a regexp of some sort, e.g. `\d{2}:\d{2}`.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to parse such time strings:

```
String time = "21:45";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
sdf.setLenient(false);  
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(time));

int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

System.out.println(hour);
System.out.println(minute);
```

```
21
45
```

You can handle the potential `ParseException` to deal with invalid inputs.

Comment: One important point is missing here, namely `setLenient(false)`, see my answer.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Yes, you're right, I'll add that to the snippet above. +1 to you.

Comment: Oh, another problem, you use hh:mm, I would use HH:mm for 24h-clock. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here a truely validating solution:

```
String time = "21:45";

boolean valid = true;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
sdf.setLenient(false); // important for validation

GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
try {
  gcal.setTime(sdf.parse(time));
} catch (ParseException pe) {
  valid = false;
}

if (valid) {
  int hours = gcal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  int minutes = gcal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  System.out.println("Hours: " + hours);
  System.out.println("Minutes: " + minutes);
} else {
  System.out.println("Sorry, the input is not valid: " + time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  String arr[]= time.split(":", 2);
  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
```

Comment: How does adding `limit` to `split` improves already posted answer?

Comment: actually it will be the same. Just got little late while typing the answer.